# AngularJs variable to FormData conversion

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an array or json array

```
var Patient = {
        PatientID : $scope.PatientID,
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.LastName,
        Disease: $scope.Disease,
        PhoneNo: $scope.PhoneNo
    };
```

I need to convert that Patient array to new FormData() by using loop

```
var patientData = new FormData();
for(var i = 0; i<=Patient.length; i++) {
    patientData.appent(Patient.Key,Patient.Value);
}
```

is this possible ?? or onsubmit, instad of creating Pating array can i directing get formdata as a FormData() or is there any another way to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var patientData = new FormData();
angular.forEach(Patient, function (value, key) {
    patientData.append(key, value);
});
```

Comment: Don't mention it. Although I wouldn't edit your post the way you did it. Please be guided by proper casing and correct sentence structure, no doubling of punctuation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var pateintData = new FormData();
for (var key in Patient) {
   patientData.append(key,Patient[key]);
}
```